# Unity2D shooting targets in order to random colors' match - C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arraylist, game-physics

I'm trying to do a game with quests in it. One of them is shooting colored targets in order the correct order which has been randomly generated. I'm stuck on detecting whether or not the player has hit the targets in the correct order.

Let's say, we have a lot of balls with their color randomized between 4 values: `Blue`, `Red`, `Grey`, and `Purple`. We show the player the order in which he needs to hit them and player tries to shoot targets in said order.

Example: If balls comes out, `Blue`, `Red`, `Grey`, and `Purple` the player must shoot the balls in that order.

I'm very new to programming and to Unity, so I don't know how to do that.

I'm giving the code which I use to randomly assign colors to sprites to give you an idea how the color works.

```
public Color[] Colors;

private void Start () 
{
    int color = Random.Range(0, Colors.Length);

    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Colors[color];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to make sure the player hits the colors in the correct order?

Firstly, there's problems with your code. `Colorize` is a verb, which should only be used for function and method names, that's why StackOverflow has given it a color, it thinks it's a function. The name sound be `Colors`. (I know, it's weird that "s" can sound like "z" in English, but there's an interesting reason).

So first, create an `enum` like this:

```
public class BallUtilities
{
    enum BallColors { Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Pink, Purple ... };

    public static Color32 ToColor(this BallColor ballColor) =>
    {
         switch (ballColor)
         {
             case BallColor.Red:  return new Color32 (255, 50, 50);
             case BallColor.Blue: return new Color32 (50,  50, 255);
             case BallColor.Green: ...
             .
             .
             .
             (etc.)
         }
    }
}
```

Now, we need to keep track of all the balls created, so:

```
public class BallManager
{
    public static List<BallColor> BallColorsSpawned = new List<BallColor>();
}
```

Then, change your current script to:

```
public void Start()
{
    Color = (BallColor)Random.Range(0, Enum.GetNames(typeof(BallColor)).Length - 1)
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().Color = Color.ToColor();
    Ballmanager.SpawnBallsColor.Add(Color);
}
```

Now we have a list of all the colors in the order the player needs to hit them. So now, wherever the player hits the balls, do something like this:

```
Ball ballHit = GetBallHit();   // Leaving it up to you to find out how to get whatever 
                               // ball was just hit stored as a variable

if (BallManager.BallColorsSpawned[0].Color == ballHit.Color)
{
    if (BallManager.BallColorsSpawned.Length == 1)
        // That was the last ball remaining, so the player wins
    else BallManager.BallColorsSpawned.RemoveAt(0);  // Remove it as no longer important
}
else 
{
    // Player hit the wrong ball, so the player loses
}
```

If you don't know what an `enum` is or extension method or anything else I've used, then stop using Unity for the time being, and go study C# extensively using practice projects on Visual Studio, online tutorials and C# In Depth by Jon Skeet. I went months of coding C# before I even installed Unity.